# Oracle - How to use & without being asked about the value?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

Basically, I don't want to be asked about the value like this::

```
SQL> select &test from dual;
Enter value for test:
```

I want only declare the `&test` along the script, something like it:

```
&test varchar2(100):= 'some value'; --of course, this don't work.
```

Comment: As per the linked duplicate, `DEFINE test = 'some value'` then `SELECT &test FROM DUAL`. Note: this is a substitution variable that is processed by the SQL client, i.e. SQL*Plus, and (typically) not by the database and only a few client applications support substitution variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute

```
SQL> set define off
```

before running your code.

---

```
SQL> select '&test' from dual;

'&TES
-----
&test

SQL>
```

---

If you want to "declare" it, then use `var`:

```
SQL> var test varchar2(200);
SQL> exec :test := 'some value';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print test

TEST
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
some value

SQL>
```

---

In dynamic SQL: I won't lock anyone, but - I'll change my password.

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> var test varchar2(200);
SQL> exec :test := 'lion';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print test

TEST
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
lion

SQL> begin
  2    execute immediate 'alter user scott identified by ' || :test;
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> connect scott/tiger
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
SQL> connect scott/lion
Connected.
SQL>
```

Comment: But how I declare &test?

Comment: "Declare" it? If it contains ampersand, it is a substitution variable. If you don't want it to be, you SET DEFINE OFF, and then it becomes an ordinary **string** so you enclose it into single quotes (see demo in the answer).

Comment: No, isn't what I look for, &test need some value like in my example, I don't what the literal &test. I only don't want a interactive script asking for values.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question; have a look, again :)

Comment: not work inside dynamic SQL, I've tried already. only &var works.
I have PLSQL code with: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter user username_here account lock' The dynamic SQL don't get the :var command. Only &var works.

Comment: It works (if you use it correctly). See another demo.

Comment: Great, worked after separate the :test from strings ' ' with ||. Thanks. unfortunately the question was closed by the community, maybe I won't specific with the question, But many thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad if it helped.